# How can I disable the advertisements shown before YouTube videos in Safari

Tags: youtube, advertisements, mac

Before creating this post I read [this similar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18453/how-can-i-disable-the-advertisements-shown-before-youtube-videos) post, but there is no solution for blocking ads in Safari. I use AdBlock version 2.6.4 for Safari 6.0.5, but it simply doesn't block YouTube ads. How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://adblock.tenderapp.com/discussions/known-bugs/6-youtube-ads-are-not-blocked) topic where says what this is a bug.